# Encountered error "NoMethodError in Posts#show"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nomethoderror

I am new in ruby on rails in windows.. I am following some [guide through youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BI_VnnOLSKY), but I encountered error

Question: In part of `<%= @post.item %>`, what should I put in `@post`?. Is it my method or the name of the field in my another view?

> "NoMethodError in Posts#show undefined method `item' for nil:NilClass
>       Extracted source (around line #2):
>       1 
>       2 <%= @post.item %> # the error indicates here
>       3 
>       4 
>       5 Submitted:<%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) %> Ago
>       6

**Controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end
    def addItem
    end
    def create
      @post = Post.new(post_params)
      @post.save
      redirect_to @post
    end
    private
        def post_params
            params.require(:post).permit(:item, :description)
        end
    def show
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

**Show.html.erb view**

```
<h1 class="item">
    <%= @post.item %>
</h1>
<h1 class="date">
    Submitted:<%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) %> Ago
</h1>
<h1 class="description">
    <%= @post.description %>
</h1>
<h1 class="date">
    Submitted:<%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) %> Ago
</h1>
```

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  resources :posts
  root "posts#index"
  resources :posts
  root "posts#addItem"
end
```

Comment: Your `@post` instance variable is `nil` that'e why you are getting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby, All the methods you add below `private` keyword becomes private methods.

In your case, show method is a private one, hence `@post` variable is not available in view.

Change your `posts_controller` code to this

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

    def index
    end

    def create
      @post = Post.new(post_params)
      @post.save
      redirect_to @post
    end

    def show
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def addItem
    end

    private
      def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:item, :description)
      end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

move your `show` method above `private`

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have "item" field in your model (table)

Comment: As pramod said, all the methods below of private will also become private :)